# jquery Datatable manipulation causing the entire page to reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable  that is initially populated using ajax call, and when i click anywhere on the table like pagination number or display length dropdown list, the **whole page is reloaded indefinetely**. Here is how i populate the datatable.

```
let table = $('#data-table').DataTable();
function populateTable(){

   table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            responsive: true,
            serverSide: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            paging: true,
            filter: true,
            searching: true,
            stateSave: true,
            scrollX: true,
            lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
            language: {
                "search": "Filtrer: "
            },
            ajax: {
                url: '/Observer/GetActiveClientsByFloor',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    FloorId: floorId,
                    Type: type
                },
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Zone',
                    data: 'LastKnownZone',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Hiérarchie Map',
                    data: 'MapInfo.mapHierarchyString',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Addresse MAC',
                    data: 'macAddress',
                },
                {
                    title: 'SSID',
                    data: 'ssId',
                },
            ],
            createdRow: (row, data, dataIndex, cells) => {

                const selectedRowProfileId = $('#selectedRowProfileId', window.parent.document).val();

                if (selectedRowProfileId !== '') {

                    if (data['ProfileId'] === selectedRowProfileId) {

                        $(row).addClass('selectedCustom');
                    }

                }
            },

            initComplete: function (settings, json)
            {
                const response = json;

                 //Show the respone on other part of the page
            }
      }).order([[1, 'asc']]).draw(false);
}
```

I would like to know what could be causing page re-load and also know how to make pagination works.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `order([[1, 'asc']]).draw(false)` after table initialization, just add

```
order: [[1, 'asc']]
```

to your table properties, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
                order: [[1, 'asc']],
                //Other properties
});
```

As you are not using `server-side`  DataTables will make pagination automatically when you click pagination buttons, considering that all data has already been loaded in the first `Ajax` call, but when `serverSide` is set to `true` every time you change the pagination a new `Ajax` call will be made by datatables sending aditional parameters for `pagination`, `ordering` etc and you will need to change you backend `query`, `filters` and `pagination` logic based on that params.

Edit:
Also `destroy: true` is not needed in your case, as [Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) says:
"Destroy any existing table matching the selector and replace with the new options." 
You are not re-creating or replacing your table, so you can just remove it

Comment: I did like you said , but still have page reloading forever. Please refer to the snapshot of the table in the post. Thanks

Comment: Can you please check if are you getting any error on console or in ajax response?

Comment: Try to remove the first line "let table=..." and remove the function populateTable, then initialize your table on $(document).ready({...}), I think this should fix it

Comment: But i need the global variable **table** in other functions so that i can change the table contents whenever the user interacts with the application.

Comment: You can keep your global variable, but just initialize it one time, like this: $(document).ready(function(){
    let table = $('#data-table').DataTable({...})
});

Comment: Ok let me do it , but also i noticed my pagination button does not work at all